# Detecting if I'm on a single, non-post, non-homepage page?

Tags: pages, page-specific-settings

I'm trying to see if I am on a single page, this page is defined by:

1. Is not the homepage for sure.
2. Doesn't have any posts for sure.

Here's my code:

```
<?php if ( !is_home() && !have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="single-page">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Added to `page.php`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I know for a fact that simply adding html code to this file adds it to every single page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `is_home()` is right, but the condition `have_post()` in the template `page.php` will be `true` because at least one **post** of type '**page**' exist. A page is already a post.

Comment: Makes sense! I still don't see how I could tweak my code to only cover not-homepage and not-posts pages.

Comment: Maybe you can create your  `custom-template.php` and select it in the page that you want from WP admin panel. If you could give me more information about the question I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_page()` to check if you're on a single page, and use `! is_front_page()` to exclude the homepage, if it's set to a static page (if it isn't `is_page()` will be false).

```
<?php if ( is_page() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <div class="single-page">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer given by **@Jacob Peattie**, is fair enough. But if you only need to add some classes to the DOM for CSS styling then you may follow other procedures too. Like WordPress by default add `home` class to home page and `single-post` class to single post. As well as for other post types `single-{post_type}`. [Have a look here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/) You'll have an overview. So you can follow nested CSS procedure to style your things as you like.

Comment: Why down vote ? Who ever down voted this please explain when you are down voting.